# React: Find if there's duplicate value into array then increment only the specific key value of the object

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating this component that will add item into the cart. The output that I want if the user add a duplicate value there's a specific key value name noOfOrder that will be incremented. My array will be stored in localStorage.

**LocalStorage**

```
0: {title: "Spicy Ramen",…}
description: "The perfect hybrid of fancy restaurant-style ramen and the pre-packaged instant noodles."
noOfOrders: 1
price: 17
title: "Spicy Ramen"

1: {title: "Spicy Chicken",…}
description: "Sweet and Spicy Chicken is perfectly crispy and coated in the most delicious, sweet, sti"
noOfOrders: 1
price: 4
title: "Spicy Chicken"
```

UseState

```
const [checkOutItems, setCheckOutItems] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CheckOutItem')) || []
  );
```

**AddToCart Function**

```
const handleAddToCart= () => {

let oldArrays = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CheckOutItem')) || [];
let itemArrays = {
  title: itemInfo.title,
  description: itemInfo.description,
  price: itemInfo.price * noOfItem || itemInfo.price,
  noOfOrders: 1,
};

if (oldArrays.some((item) => item.title === itemArrays.title)) {
 const match = oldArrays.findIndex(
    (product) => product.title === itemArrays.title
  );
  if (match) {
    match.noOfOrders++;
  }
  oldArrays[oldArrays.findIndex((el) => el.title === match.title)] = match;
  localStorage.setItem('CheckOutItem', JSON.stringify(oldArrays));
} else {
  setCheckOutItems((prev) => [...prev, itemArrays]);
  oldArrays.push(itemArrays);
}

localStorage.setItem('CheckOutItem', JSON.stringify(oldArrays));
  };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your code in codesandbox. It would be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will mutate the products so make sure it's a clone or if you parsing from localstorage then you don't really need to clone as this object is created

```js
const key = 'cart'
const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
const match = products.find(product => product.id === id);
if (match) {
  match.count++;
}
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(products));
```

Comment: I've set up a small codesandbox for demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moser-8shk0

Comment: Thanks sir @Dvir, The only problem is i'm having issue on how to update the state. Based on my code after i stored the data to my localstorage then it also stored on my useState.